# Xcode 7.3.1 can't build from the commandline swift-build missing

Tags: xcode, macos

[OSX 10.11.6, Xcode 7.3.1]

I have Xcode 7.3.1 installed from the App Store and I can compile Swift code inside the IDE.  However, I am unable to build from the commandline.  When I try to, I get an error:

```
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build (No such file or directory)
```

I don't have a `toolchain` tab in my `Preferences -> Components` dialog, which, according to other threads I've read, is because I don't have any other toolchains installed.  Since, according to Apple, Swift 2.2.1 came with Xcode 7.3.1  (but my --version reports 2.2), what command can I issue to create the /Library/Developer/Toolchain folder (or other variations that will work) that will allow me to build from the command line?

The SnapShot master trunk is up to Swift 3, which is not suitable for my needs and I don't want to (can't afford to) download another gig of data, when I already have the compiler, linker, etc.  And I prefer not to have a `-dev` version of Swift.

Please help.

Additional info:

```
swift --version
Apple Swift version 2.2 (swiftlang-703.0.18.8 clang-703.0.31)

which swift
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift

swift build
error: unable to invoke subcommand: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-build (No such file or directory)
```

Comment: The same for me...

Comment: [**`Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.1`**](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.1/Command_Line_Tools_OS_X_10.11_for_Xcode_7.3.1.dmg)

Comment: @I'L'I:  I can't access that page: `This page no longer exists or the Apple ID you signed in with does not have permission to view this page. If you’re currently a member of the Apple Developer Program, you or your Team Agent may need to update your account by agreeing to the latest license agreement in order to access this page.`

Comment: Also, I have the command line tools installed already.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `swift-build` is available in Swift 2.2.1 (Xcode 7.3.1), as it's part of the [Package Manager](https://swift.org/package-manager/) which is Swift 3 only:

> The Package Manager will be released with Swift 3 and is currently only available with the Swift 3 development snapshots.